# managedObjectContext seems to delete my NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults, nsmanagedobjectcontext

saving the managedObjectContext seems to eat the NSUserDefault

```
NSString *defaultSiteUrl = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSelectedSiteUrlKey];
NSLog(@"the default site url is: %@", defaultSiteUrl);

if (![[managedObjectContext] save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Error saving entity: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

NSString *defaultSiteUrl2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kSelectedSiteUrlKey];
NSLog(@" the default site url is: %@", defaultSiteUrl2);
```

Result in the console:

```
2011-05-10 15:26:40.710 Moodle[44566:207] the default site url is: http://jerome.moodle.local/~jerome/Moodle_iPhone
2011-05-10 15:26:40.717 Moodle[44566:207] the default site url is: (null)
```

What could cause this issue? 
In which way is NSUserDefaults related with ManagedObjectContext?

Note:

- To let you know my application: I'm developping a Moodle app. This piece code is on a screen displaying a list of courses. I use [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] when I set the userdefault on a "site settings" screen. So I guess it's well saved
- The piece of code works (the user defaults are not deleted by the "save manageObjectContext") if I restart the simulator before going to the course listing screen straight after setting the user default.

Comment: What code do you use to set that key in the user defaults? Are you sure that you do not have a threaded call that is overriding the settings and synchronizing the defaults in background?

Comment: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[settingsSiteViewController.site valueForKey:@"url"] forKey:kSelectedSiteUrlKey];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` It's pretty simple. There is only two place changing this user defaults. I keep going to have a look, but I don't get it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize the NSUserDefaults value by [NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:appDefaults], using synchronize method for instiliaztioan could destroy you user defaults, NOTE, **it's nothing to do with core data**.

Comment: Thanks Dongsheng, registerDefaults did seem to fix the problem. I still would like to know what happen behind the "save manageObjectContext" :)